# Windows GUI Tool for testing Web-APIs

Tags: windows, gui, http, web-apis

Is there a ms-windows GUI Tool (or browser plug-in) for testing Web-APIs?

required features:

- basic-auth support
- JSON and XML should be displayed in a "pretty" way.
- Supports HTTP GET and POST
- Ignoring invalid SSL certs is needed.
- No need to support SOAP. Just simple URLs with JSON/XML response.
- commercial ok, but open source is preferred.

Please leave a comment, if something is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

https://insomnia.rest/ works very well for me. You can do a bunch of things to aid rrequest re-use (import/export configs, workspaces, environment variables, etc).

I'm not sure about "Ignoring invalid SSL certs is needed." but it seems to use libcurl under the covers and will do whatever that does.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com)!  Postman is not open source, but there seems to be a free version available.

Comment: A combination of Postman and Selenium should be all that is required to test almost any web app.